# Comparison between String and Numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have some code like these:

```
let url = "/user_auth/devices";

const params = ["clientId = 909090", "name = peter", "active = true"];

for (let i=0; i < params.length; i++) {
        url += i > 0 ? "&" + params[i] : "?" + params[i];
    }
```

The output will be something like: `"/user_auth/devices?clientId = 909090&name = peter&active = true"`;

What I don't understand is that inside the for loop, since `url` is a string, how does a string plus a number being greater than 0?

I've tested with it:

when `url` plus 0, the output is `/user_auth/devices0` and turns to be `false` when compare with 0.

when `/user_auth/devices0` plus 1 the output is `/user_auth/devices01` and the result is also false when compare with 0.

Does anyone know why a string plus 0 could be greater than 0?

Comment: Some brackets could help. It's actually `url += (i > 0 ? ("&" + params[i]) : ("?" + params[i]));`

Answer (score 2):

This `url += i > 0 ? "&" + params[i] : "?" + params[i];` is just syntactic sugar (it is called the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), which is equivalent) to:

```
if (i > 0) {
    url += "&" + params[i];
} else {
    url += "?" + params[i];
}
```

`i` is not being added to `url`, and only `i` is being compared to `0`. And it could also be reduced to this (by factoring out `params[i]`):

```
url += (i > 0 ? "&" : "?") + params[i];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a ternary expression:

```
i > 0 ? "&" + params[i] : "?" + params[i];
```

It will return `"&" + params[i]` when `i` is higher than `0` and `"?" + params[i]` otherwise.

In your code, you are using the `+=` operator which adds the value returned from your ternary expression to the url.

To summarize, you are not comparing a `string` and a `number` with `0`. You are adding the result from a ternary operation to a `string` (your variable `url`).

Answer (score 1):

the interpreter evaluates the code from right to left.

Thus in `url += i > 0 ? "&" + params[i] : "?" + params[i];`

it starts by evaluating the result of `i > 0 ? "&" + params[i] : "?" + params[i]`, then, it concatenates the result in `url +=...`

as other has shown, this code can be written such as:

```js
if (i > 0) {
    url += "&";
} else {
    url += "?";
}
url += params[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

The snippet `url += i > 0` is not performing a comparison between the `url` (a string) and `0` (a number), rather it does a comparison between `i` (the loop counter) and the constant `0`; and both are numbers.

In order to understand what is happening, you first have to understand two things:

- the ternary operator `?:`
- the shortcut assignment operator `+=`

I will address the shortcut assignment operator first. Then I will explain the ternary operator.

#### The shortcut assignment operator: `+=`

The shortcut assignment operator lets you increment and assign a value in one step. Rather than doing something like this:

`a = a + 5; // first increment a by 5, then assign the result to a`

This operator lets you do something like this:

`a += 5; // increment and assign the result of increment a by 5 in one step`

#### The ternary operator: `?:`

The ternary operator is a shortcut way to perform an `if...else` operation. It is called a **ternary** operator because it accepts three (3) operands. For example, the classical `if...else` statement is written like this:

```
if(condition) {
  // code to execute if condition is true
} else {
  // code to execute otherwise
}
```

The ternary operator lets you do the above in a more elegant and concise way:

`condition ? code_to_execute_if_condition_is_true : code_to_execute_otherwise`

In the above snippet, the operator is the `?:`, and the operands are as follows:

- `condition`
- `code_to_execute_if_condition_is_true`
- `code_to_execute_otherwise`

The operation can also be broken into two parts:

- The first part is the part from the  `condition` up until the `:`, and is similar to the `if(condition)` of a classical `if...else`. If that condition is true, the code between the `?` and the `:` will be executed. It is just as if you wrote:

  ```
  if(condition) {
      // code_to_execute_if_condition_is_true
  }
  ```
- The second part is the part following the `:`, and the code following it is executed if the condition is false. It is as if you wrote:

  ```
  else {
      // code_to_execute_otherwise
  }
  ```

  **Important**: But please note that the ternary operator is one: `?:` you cannot use either part in isolation. They must always be used as specified above.

#### Addressing the issue at hand

Now, coming to the issue at hand, this is your code:

```
let url = "/user_auth/devices";

const params = ["clientId = 909090", "name = peter", "active = true"];

for (let i=0; i < params.length; i++) {
   url += i > 0 ? "&" + params[i] : "?" + params[i];
}
```

I will first explain the part inside the loop:

`url += i > 0 ? "&" + params[i] : "?" + params[i];`

This code snippet can be split into two parts:

- `url +=`

  Based on what we have explained so far, this is a shortcut way of writing:

  `url = url + // something (we will get to that something in a bit)`
- `i > 0 ? "&" + params[i] : "?" + params[i];`
  This is the ternary operator at play here, and it is like writing:

  ```
  if(i > 0) {
     return "&" + params[i];
  } else {
      return "?" + params[i];
  }
  ```

  Earlier, we talked about `url +=` as being equivalent to `url = url + // something`. That `something` is what is returned from the second part:

  `i > 0 ? "&" + params[i] : "?" + params[i];`.

  And whatever that is is tacked onto the end of the url.
  So that if `i` is greater than `0` (which is the case in all but the first iteration), the `url` will be

  `url = url + "&" + params[i]`.

  However, if `i` is `0` (which is the case on the first iteration), the `url` will be

  `url = url + "?" + params[i]`.

  Since your initial `url` string is: `"/user_auth/devices";`, substituting the different iteration values for `params[i]`, we will have:

  - on the first iteration,

    `i === 0`

    `params[i]` equals `"clidenId = 909090"`

    So, we will have `url = url + "?" + "clientId = 909090"`.

    Resulting in: `"/user_auth/devices?clientId = 909090";`
  - On the second iteration,

    `i === 1` (and therefore greater than 0)

    `params[i]` equals `"name = peter"`

    we will have `url = url + "&" + "name = peter"`

    Resulting in: `"/user_auth/devices?clientId = 909090&name = peter";`
  - The same process is repeated on the third iteration (and any subsequent iteration if you add some other elements to the `params` array). But since `i` will  be greater than `0` in all subsequent iterations, the result will be obtained via a similar process to the second iteration.

Answer (score 0):

1. Any string is > 0 but you just have a poorly written [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) that tests if the loop is iteration 0 or higher
2. use the URLSeachParams, then no need to test the & or ?

```js
const params = ["clientId = 909090", "name = peter", "active = true"];
const sp = new URLSearchParams()
params.forEach(parm => {
  const [name,value] = parm.split("=");
  sp.set(name.trim(),value.trim()); // trim could be avoided if you had a proper key/value object
})
console.log("/user_auth/devices?"+sp.toString())
```

Your unpleasant array can be processed with some simple replace too

```js
const params = ["clientId = 909090", "name = peter", "active = true"];

const search = "?"+params.toString().replace(/\s+/g,"").replace(/,/g,"&")

console.log(search)
```